# 2 check boxes to have individual purposes singularly and a purpose when both selected using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have 2 checkboxes on a page, I have called them addon1checkbox and addon2checkbox. When you click addon1checkbox this should have an individual purpose, when you click on addon2checkbox this should have an individual purpose, when both of them are selected this should have a different purpose. I have got the 2 individuals working ok but I am lost for both of them. When both are selected the button with class="both" should be displayed. Here is the fiddle:

```js
$('.addon1checkbox').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.addon1checkbox').each(function() {
      this.checked = true;
    });

    $('button').each(function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });

    $('.addon1').each(function() {
      $(this).show();
    });
  } else {
    $('.addon1checkbox').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });

    $('button').each(function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });

    $('.normal').each(function() {
      $(this).show();
    });
  }
});

$('.addon2checkbox').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.addon2checkbox').each(function() {
      this.checked = true;
    });

    $('button').each(function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });

    $('.addon2').each(function() {
      $(this).show();
    });
  } else {
    $('.addon2checkbox').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });

    $('button').each(function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });

    $('.normal').each(function() {
      $(this).show();
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.product {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

button {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.addon1,
.addon2,
.both {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <label>
    Addon 1
    <input type="checkbox" class="addon1checkbox">
  </label>
  <label>
    Addon 2
    <input type="checkbox" class="addon2checkbox">
  </label>
  <div>
    <button class="normal">
      Normal
    </button>
    <button class="addon1">
      Addon 1
    </button>
    <button class="addon2">
      Addon 2
    </button>
    <button class="both">
      Both
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <label>
    Addon 1
    <input type="checkbox" class="addon1checkbox">
  </label>
  <label>
    Addon 2
    <input type="checkbox" class="addon2checkbox">
  </label>
  <div>
    <button class="normal">
      Normal
    </button>
    <button class="addon1">
      Addon 1
    </button>
    <button class="addon2">
      Addon 2
    </button>
    <button class="both">
      Both
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle if you prefer:

https://jsfiddle.net/ng5bqc1j/1/

Comment: What is expected behaviour? can you give a step by step with expected and actual behaviour?

Comment: So when both are selected then the buttons with class="both" should be displayed. I will update my question, thanks @mplungjan

Comment: Is the checking of two checkboxes by one click by design?

Comment: My answer that I found is towards the bottom. Appreciate any help if there are other ways for my learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So add the functionality together and check the states onchange

```
$('.addon1checkbox, .addon2checkbox').on("change", function () {
  var cb1 = $('.addon1checkbox').is(':checked');
  var cb2 = $('.addon2checkbox').is(':checked');
  if (cb1 && cb2) {}
  else if (cb1) {}
  else if (cb2) {}
  else {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look of this simpler script

```js
$('.product [type=checkbox]').on("change",function() {
  const $parent = $(this).closest(".product");
  const checked = $('[type=checkbox]',$parent).filter(function() { return this.checked }).get()
  $('.both',$parent).toggle(checked.length===2)
  $('.normal',$parent).toggle(checked.length!==2)
});
```

```css
.product {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

button {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.addon1,
.addon2,
.both {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <label>
    Addon 1
    <input type="checkbox" class="addon1checkbox">
  </label>
  <label>
    Addon 2
    <input type="checkbox" class="addon2checkbox">
  </label>
  <div>
    <button class="normal">
      Normal
    </button>
    <button class="addon1">
      Addon 1
    </button>
    <button class="addon2">
      Addon 2
    </button>
    <button class="both">
      Both
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <label>
    Addon 1
    <input type="checkbox" class="addon1checkbox">
  </label>
  <label>
    Addon 2
    <input type="checkbox" class="addon2checkbox">
  </label>
  <div>
    <button class="normal">
      Normal
    </button>
    <button class="addon1">
      Addon 1
    </button>
    <button class="addon2">
      Addon 2
    </button>
    <button class="both">
      Both
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lovely simple little script, but it doesn't load the button for Addon 1 when that is clicked individually, or load the button for Addon 2 when that is clicked individually.

Comment: Possible - you had a very complicated set of rules - I’ll look in a little while

Comment: Maybe question wasn't thorough enough. If addon1checkbox is selected that button is loaded, if addon2checkbox is selected that button is loaded, if both are selected that button is loaded, if none are selected normal button is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Here was my answer with huge thanks to @epascarello.

```js
$('.addon1checkbox').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.addon1checkbox').each(function() {
      this.checked = true;
    });
  } else {
    $('.addon1checkbox').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
  }
});

$('.addon2checkbox').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.addon2checkbox').each(function() {
      this.checked = true;
    });
  } else {
    $('.addon2checkbox').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
  }
});

$('.addon1checkbox, .addon2checkbox').change(function() {
  $('button').each(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });

  var cb1 = $('.addon1checkbox').is(':checked');
  var cb2 = $('.addon2checkbox').is(':checked');
  if (cb1 && cb2) {
    $('.both').each(function() {
      $(this).show();
    });
  } else if (cb1) {
    $('.addon1').each(function() {
      $(this).show();
    });
  } else if (cb2) {
    $('.addon2').each(function() {
      $(this).show();
    });
  } else {
    $('.normal').each(function() {
      $(this).show();
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.product {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

button {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.addon1,
.addon2,
.both {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <label>
    Addon 1
    <input type="checkbox" class="addon1checkbox">
  </label>
  <label>
    Addon 2
    <input type="checkbox" class="addon2checkbox">
  </label>
  <div>
    <button class="normal">
      Normal
    </button>
    <button class="addon1">
      Addon 1
    </button>
    <button class="addon2">
      Addon 2
    </button>
    <button class="both">
      Both
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <label>
    Addon 1
    <input type="checkbox" class="addon1checkbox">
  </label>
  <label>
    Addon 2
    <input type="checkbox" class="addon2checkbox">
  </label>
  <div>
    <button class="normal">
      Normal
    </button>
    <button class="addon1">
      Addon 1
    </button>
    <button class="addon2">
      Addon 2
    </button>
    <button class="both">
      Both
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle if you prefer:

https://jsfiddle.net/2jx6tvLw/2/